# PayPal Pro Direct Payment using Credit Card

Tags: onepage-checkout, paypal, name, paypal-payments-pro, paypal-pro

Finished setting up PayPal Pro direct payment. For credit/debit card options, it does not ask for Name on the card. Only card numbers, CVN expiration etc. So, does it just assume the same name that was entered in the previous billing information step or it just doesn't need any name on the card?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that you're doing this on a Magento 2.x site? One of the key things that was done with Magento 2 was a streamlining of the checkout process.  The less you need to ask for, the faster a customer can part with their money.  So fields like name on card and credit card type were removed.  And the system also uses assumes that your billing and shipping address is the same.  Because for most people, it is.  (That said, I prefer to have stuff shipped to the office, because there's usually someone there to sign for it.)

Because of this, the system doesn't ask for the name on the card, and uses the billing name instead.  The logic is that for 99% of the time, the billing name and the name on the card are going to be pretty much the same. If you have a high-fraud industry, you can tell people that the billing name should match the name on the card (using a note under or next to the billing address.)

Same thing with not asking if the card is a Visa, Mastercard, Amex.  Amex cards start with the number 3; Visa cards all start with the number 4; Mastercards start with 5.  Discover might be 6 or 8, but it's not used very much these days.

Here's a screenshot of the simplified checkout for a credit card (this is using BrainTree, which is a PayPal product):
[image: Simplified Credit card checkout]

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks Jeff. Good to know. I should probably notify customers that name in the billing info must match the name on the card.